# Why can one multiply sections by numbers?

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been reading Nakahara's "Geometry, Topology and Physics" an came to the point that I don't understand something very basic. Speaking about the covariant derivative on associated bundles he defines the following: Let  $P(M, G)$ be a $G$ bundle over $M$. Associated with $P$ is a vector bundle $E = P \times_\rho V$. A section $s(p) \in \Gamma(M,E)$ is an element of the form $s(p) = [(\sigma_i(p), \chi(p))]$, where $\sigma$ is a section of $P$ and $\chi \in V$as I get it.
Later in exercise 10.8 we are asked to show that $\nabla_x(a_1s_1 + a_2s_2) = a_1\nabla_xs_1 + a_2\nabla_xs_2$ where $a_i \in R, s_i \in \Gamma(M,E)$. I don't get how one is supposed to multiply $s$ by a number or sum them because when I try to do it naively, namely $a_1s_1 + a_2s_2 = [(a_1\sigma_1(p) + a_2\sigma_2(p),a_1\chi_1(p)) + a_2\chi_2(p) )]$ I find out that the first component of s $\sigma(p)$ takes values in the group $G$ so I don't know how to multiply it by number or sum.

Comment: You only do the scaling and adding in the second factor, which is a vector space.

Comment: Is $P$ supposed to be a principal $G$-bundle? Or does $G$ at least act transitively on the fibers of $P$? I ask this because, as @MichaelAlbanese said, you should apply vector operations only on the $\chi$ part of your section $s$, but (as he didn't say) you should do so when the $\sigma$ parts are the same. For a principal bundle $P$, you can arrange for the $\sigma$'s to agree, thanks to the equivalence relation that defines $[(\sigma,\chi)]$. But for general bundles $P$, I see no way to add sections of $M$.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is a principal bundle and I think the $\sigma$ parts are supposed to be the same, as I understand now $i$ in $\sigma_i$ denotes the chart to which the section refers being the section which defines canonical local trivialization. Thank you all for clarifications.